# Angular2 Indian number separator pipe with 3,2,2 series

Tags: angular

The Angular decimal pipe for India (with 'IN' as locale) uses the 3,2,2,2... series for separators (e.g.: 10,00,00,00,000).

However, in India the entire series (3,2,2) is commonly repeated as 3,2,2,3,2,2,... so that the lakhs, crores, thousands can be easily read. The above number would be displayed as 1,000,00,00,000 (read as One thousand crores).

Is this supported using Angular's pipes or how to implement this?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system):

> The Indian numbering system uses separators differently from the international norm. Instead of grouping digits by threes in international system, the grouping is done in repeating pattern of 3,2,2 (from least significant digits). This makes the number convenient read using thousand, lakh, crore terminology.

Comment: @Vikash that answer still gives the format as 3,2,2,2,2,2.... instead of 3,2,2,3,2,2

Answer (score 0):

I"ve just open sourced [paisa.js](https://github.com/sudhirj/paisa.js), you can use that as a custom formatter instead of the default Angular formatter.

You're using extremely large numbers, though - not sure if I've tested that far, but you can always raise a PR if what you expect isn't working.